# cart API of word-press woo-commerce

Tags: wordpress, flutter, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I was trying to build a grocery app using flutter with woo-commerce as a backend. there is an app already with the same woo-commerce using native code but no source code available is there any way to get the cart API used in the old app as I have the admin account and other data of woo-commerce site??

Answer (score 0):

it is only possible if you have that web App Api then you can get the data and if you have the access of that web app admin panel why you not create another api for your self and make flutter app on that api..

i think this is the only solution you have to resolve this problem

Comment: is creating another api causes lossing old cart data??

Comment: i don't think so because you have admin access so it's up to you how you utilize your admin access. if there are thousands of cart data then it will be little complex and handy to create another api. for that you need to get old api back

Answer (score 0):

```
url: '/wp-json/wc/store/cart/add-item',
```

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.

Comment: Try this api url with your site ?